# Universal font styling for forms in Rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts

I am trying to edit the font and styling of all form labels in my Rails app. Is there one CSS class I can use that will apply to all form fonts across the app?

The current section I am trying to change is:

```
<%= f.label :username %>
<%= f.text_field :username %>

<%= f.label :bio %>
<%= f.text_area :bio, :cols => "80", :rows => "10" %>

<%= label_tag "Profile Picture" %>
<%= collection_select(:user, :profile_picture_id, ProfilePicture.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
```

I would like the `:username`, `:bio`, and `"Profile Picture"` labels to be in a different font without specifying a `class` parameter in each one.

Comment: To GameDroids: In my opinion you significantly edited the code in this question by removing the `<br>`s. @Emily please clarify whether you intended for the code breaks to be there.

Comment: While removing the inline `<br>` from the ERB seems a bit much, in reality it doesn't affect the question at all, only the rendered output if sent to a browser. Even the rendered output would reflect what the question is about, only the fields themselves would be in the wrong positions. In my opinion it's a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply your CSS rules to tags too:

In plain CSS:

```js
label {
    /* Attributes that apply to all label tags */
    font: 16px sans-serif;
}
```